# Rails keeping track of what Js is doing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm in the process of designing a product configurator. The issue seemed to be that literally for every product there's multiple components, and the way they interact with each other is quite random. So if you change the quantity on one part, somewhere else it will need to be adjusted automatically etc.

Because of all this, and the fact that these rules often change, I've decided to make them into Js functions, so I have rails things like these:

```
<% @counter = 0 %>
<% @people.each do |p| %>
<% @counter += 1 %>
<tr>
<%= form_for(:p, :remote => true)  do |f| %>
<th><%= f.label(p.name) %></th>
<th><%= f.label(p.country.name) %></th>
<th><%= f.label(p.state.name) %></th>
<th id="<%= "money_" + @counter.to_s %>"> <%= f.select(:money, 1..10, :selected => p.money)%></th>
<th id="<%= "comment_" + @counter.to_s %>"><%=p.money_comment%></th>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

(field names here are random)

and I have a Js function in a file which gets loaded, like this:

```
function change_people() {
  money1 = $('money_1').children[0].value;
  $('comment_2').update((money1 == 5) ? "selected 5!" : 'why not 5?');
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  change_people();
  $('money_1').children[0].observe('change', change_people);
});
```

So this works, I could modify the values depending on what the user selected etc, but... here's the question. How does rails know about this? 
Rails brought the default number of people, which their values from the DB, etc, how do i tell it what the new value is if/when I want to add to cart?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to submit the values of the form whenever they change. For example, if you are using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$('.money').change(function(){ $(this).closest('form').submit(); });
```

This code says that anytime an input with the class 'money' is adjusted, simply submit the closest form (which happens to be the remote form you defined).

As an additional tip, you don't need to keep track of the counter with an explicit variable as you do in your code example, you can also use each_with_index:

```
@people.each_with_index do |p, counter|
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Pan. I still haven't figured out a way to properly store the different ranges and options in the db, for rails to pick them up. For default values there's no problem. But how do you think i should give it these rules as obviously storing every posible form in the db is too much. Just to give you some background, at the moment, the UI is Excel, and the "rules" are stored as strings in the db. When the user selects a product these strings (which happen to be excel formulas) are brought, so certain elements become dynamic when something changes.

Comment: I think that depends on how often you want to be able to adjust these formulas.  If they are very static you could code them directly into javascript and maintain that in your code base.  If they change often then you can store them in the DB and have an admin interface for managing them.  On a page load you could query the DB for the rules and pass them to the client.  You could also make an AJAX call when a product is selected to load the associated rules from Rails into Javascript.

Comment: The rules change often, as well as new products being introduced with their own rules. When you say "If they change often then you can store them in the DB and have an admin interface for managing them", do you mean store them as js code or as ruby code?

Comment: That's really up to you and how you are using them.  Ideally you won't store code in your database, but you'll store rules in some other format, for example: when product=a, and condition=x, then result=y, so store [a,x,y], that can be interpreted using either Ruby or Javascript code.